# In Android studio 2.2.1 java.bean.* not found

Tags: java, android, android-studio, opencsv

I am trying to use opencsv library jar file but while importing i am getting the error message saying "Fail to load plugin descriptor from file *.jar".

I checked for META-INF/plugin.xml file inside the jar, but there is none.

So, i am now importing the source code of opencsv. I am getting error with java 7 api used within the library source code. All the usages of 'java.bean.*' package is giving 'cannot find symbol' error.

Following is the `build.gradle` file content:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.amadeus.jbisht.mytestproject"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.+'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Please let me know what am I missing here. I can see it listed under 'External Libraries' but android studio isnt picking it up.

Answer (score 0):

Gradle dependencies are the way to go:

```
compile group: 'com.opencsv', name: 'opencsv', version: '3.8+'
```

E.g.,

```
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
  compile group: 'com.opencsv', name: 'opencsv', version: '3.8+'
}
```

Gradle will automatically import the required files and integrate the library.

Answer (score 0):

opencsv need some `java.bean` libraries, but they are not included in the Android SDK.

To resolve this :

- download sources of opencsv
- download [openbean](https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/openbeans/openbeans-1.0.jar)
- include both in your Android Studio project
- replace `java.bean.*` dependancies by `localpath.bean.*` in opencsv sources